# First two n such that $1355297$ divides$10^{6n+5}-54n-46$ for $n>0$

Tags: equation-solving, number-theory

I have problem solving this equation, smallest n such that $1355297$ divides $10^{6n+5}-54n-46$. I tried everything using my scientific calculator, but I never got the correct results(!).and finally I gave up!. Could you help me find the first 2 solutions for this equation ? (thanks.)

Comment: What did you try in MMA?

Comment: @Ulrich What is MMA ?

Comment: Sorry, Mathematica

Comment: O yes I am quite sure that $1355297$ divides $(10^{1836828602912}-9*1836828602911-10)$. I calculated this with my calculator.

Comment: Where does this question originate from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$n_1 = 2331259$, $n_2 = 3776127$,

Obtained from this Mathematica code:

```
cf = Compile[{{m, _Integer}},
  Block[{n, a, b, p, counter = 0,result},
   result = ConstantArray[0, m];
   p = 1355297;
   n = 0;
   a = Mod[10^(5), p];
   b = 0;
   While[counter < m,
    n++;
    a = Mod[a 1000000, p];
    b = Mod[b - 54 , p];
    While[Mod[a + b - 46, 1355297] != 0,
     n++;
     a = Mod[a 1000000, p];
     b = Mod[b - 54 , p];
     ];
    counter++;
    result[[counter]] = n;
    ];
   result
   ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ];

cf[2]
```

> {2331259, 3776127}

Comment: Thanks Henrik I really appreciate this ! : D

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 11):

There is no need for a brute force search. There is also no need for compilation, which may run into the maximum compiled integer limit. A faster solution follows from a bit of theory. You can get the first 225000 solutions (up to $n\approx 306$ billion) in less than a second.

The original equation is ${\rm Mod}[10^{6n+5}-54n-46,p]=0$, where $p=1355297$.

Let $m=6n+5$ and write the equation as `PowerMod[10,m,p]=Mod[9m+1,p]`.

The period of the cycle of `PowerMod[10,x,p]` for $x=1,2,3,...$ equals the period of the decimal expansion of $1/p$, for prime $p$. The length of the repeating decimal of $1/p$ is `MultiplicativeOrder[10,p]` which, in this case, equals $p-1$.

```
MultiplicativeOrder[10, 1355297]
```

> 1355296

These are all 1355296 distinct residues in the repeating cycle. This pre-calculation takes about 3/4 second.

```
residues = PowerMod[10, Range[1355296], 1355297]
```

The two modular equations are:

$m=i+j*(p-1)$, mod $p$, with $1\le i \le p-1$, and $j\ge 1$, from length-$(p-1)$ cycle of residues for `PowerMod[10,m,p]`

$9m+1=k*p+r_i$, mod $p$, with $0\le k$, from `Mod[9m+1,p]=ri`, the i'th residue.

Multiply the first equation by 9 and equate to give $a*j+b*k=c$, where $a=9*(p-1)$, $b=-p$, and $c=r_i-1-9*i$. Solve this linear Diophantine equation via `ExtendedGCD[a,b]`.

```
ExtendedGCD[9(p-1),-p]={g,{u,v}}
```

> {1, {301177, 2710591}}

Only the first term, $u=301177$, of the second part is required.

There are infinitely many solutions $\{j,k\}=\{u*c+b*q,v*c-a*q\}$, where $q\ge $0 and $a*u+b*v=1$ is found via `ExtendendGCD[a,b]`. The smallest solution occurs when `q=Quotient[u*c,p]`. The last step is to sort those solutions $m$ equivalent to 5, mod 6.

The first roughly quarter million solutions are found in about 1/4 second. The fastest of the current 3 answers was from @MichaelE2, where the first 10 solutions are found in about 0.68 s.

```
Block[{p = 1355297, i, u, uc},
   u = ExtendedGCD[9 (p - 1), -p][[2, 1]];
   AbsoluteTiming[
      i = Range[Length[residues]];
      uc = u*(residues[[i]] - 1 - 9 i);
      (Sort[Pick[#, Mod[#, 6], 5] &[i + (p - 1) (uc - p*Quotient[uc, p])]] - 5)/6
  ]]
```

> {0.230856, {2331259, 3776127, 5366598, 5505709, 5652052, 7317951,...,
>      306133783114, 306135079824, 306136273333}}

Subsequent solutions follow by decreasing the integer `q=Quotient[uc,p]`.

Comment: Nice. Note that `residues = NestList[Mod[10 #, 1355297] &, 10, Length@# - 1] &[Range[1355296]]` is about 16 times faster than `PowerMod`, which makes the cost of pre-computing `residues` almost insignificant. (I figure `PowerMod` is advantageous when a single or sporadic values are needed.)

Comment: @MichaelE2  Thanks for the tip here and before on slow `PowerMod`. I use it frequently, and will redefine it using your much faster `NestList` formulation.

Answer (score 8):

A more *Mathematica* way to do an exhaustive search:

```
pp = 1355297;
Pick[#,
 Mod[10^5 NestList[Mod[10^6 #, pp] &, 10^6, Length@# - 1] - (54 n + 46 /. n -> #), pp],
 0] &@ Range[10^7] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.665031, {2331259, 3776127, 5366598, 5505709, 5652052, 7317951, 8306396, 8955772}} *)
```

The same applied to chunks, which quits after at least 2 solutions are found.

```
Last@NestWhile[
  Function[args,            (* args = {current range, current solutions *)
   With[{range = Range @@ args[[1]], sols = args[[2]]},
    With[{s = Flatten[{
         sols,
         Pick[range, 
          Mod[10^5 NestList[Mod[10^6 #, pp] &, 
              PowerMod[10^6, First@range, pp], 
              Length@range - 1] - (54 n + 46 /. n -> range),
           pp],
          0]
         }]},
     {args[[1]] + 10^6, s}  (* increment range *)
     ]]
   ],
  {{1, 10^6}, {}},          (* {initial range, initial solutions *)
  Length[#[[2]]] < 2 &,     (* min. number of solutions *)
  1,
  100                       (* MaxIterations *)
  ] // RepeatedTiming

(*  {0.27, {2331259, 3776127}}  *)
```

Somewhat surprisingly, it is faster than Henrik's compiled-to-C solution:

```
cf[2] // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.283, {2331259, 3776127}}  *)
```

*Remark:* Disappointingly, [`PowerMod`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerMod.html) is slow, so I used `NestList`:

```
foo = NestList[Mod[10^6 #, pp] &, 10^6, Length@# - 1] &[Range[10^7]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.480641, Null}  *)

murf = PowerMod[10^6, Range[10^7], pp]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {7.97349, Null}  *)

foo == murf
(*  True  *)
```

Comment: Very interesting! I tried to Complie your Mathematica Pick[]-approach, hoping to speed it up, but didn't succeed. What's wrong with `find = Compile[{{mr, _Integer , 1}, {pz, _Integer }},
  Block[{},
    Pick[mr,
    Mod[10^5 NestList[Mod[10^6 mr, pz] &, 10^6, Length[mr] - 1]
      - (54 mr + 46),
     pz ](*Mod*), 0] ]
  ]`?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Unfortunately, `Pick` is [not compilable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101/4999).

Comment: @ Michael E2: It's a pity,thanks.

Answer (score 7):

How about this?

```
cf = Compile[{{max, _Integer}, {p, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}},
   Module[{list = ConstantArray[0, 0]},
    Do[
     If[
      PowerMod[10, 6 n + 5, p] - Mod[54 n + 46, p] == 0,
      AppendTo[list, n];
      If[Length[list] >= j, Break[]]
      ],
     {n, Range[1, max]}
     ];
    list
    ]
   ];

In[20]:= result = cf[10^8, 1355297, 2]

Out[20]= {2331259, 3776127}
```

Check the result:

```
In[21]:= Table[Mod[10^(6 n + 5) - 54 n - 46, 1355297], {n, result}]

Out[21]= {0, 0}
```

Comment: Hmpf. You beat me by 31 seconds... =)

Comment: =). I'm also going to say that my use of `PowerMod` is quite clever here.

Comment: Nah, it isn't... Check the timings. ;o) But I actually was looking for something like `PowerMod` but did not find it for some reason...

Comment: Why not the simple and obvious `list = {}` rather than the more obscure `list = ConstantArray[0, 0]`?

Comment: I tried `list = {}`, but for some reason this coerces all elements added to the list to reals. `ConstantArray[0, 0]` was the easiest method I found to create an empty integer list.

Comment: You can also use `list = Most@{0}`.  I don't claim that's less obscure, but I've seen others do it.